# using quick sort algorithm with the first number use as pivot

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
10,2,5,15,20,9,17,8,25,30,4
```

what would be the result of 1st round of the quick sort? the first element is the pivot which is 10 in this example

here is my answer:

```
10,4,8,9,20,15,17,5,25,30,2
```

I'm confuse. I googled and watch some videos about using quick sort algorithm but it seems there are different ways on how to do this algorithm . can someone give me advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be :

```
4,8,9,5,2,10,20,15,17,25,30
```

Quicksort takes the pivot and put it in the right place. The it start again with the two subarrays that have been created.

For the first round, it means that any element that is smaller than the pivot will be before the pivot, and any element bigger, will be after.

Comment: thanks! but how did it end up 4,8,9,5,2 and 20,15,17,25,30 exactly? that's where i'm having trouble

Comment: 10 is bigger than 4,8,9,5,2 and smaller than 20,15,17,25,30

Comment: i mean regards with the order . .

Comment: Oh, that is free to the implementation of the quicksort. It could be any order in fact. The only condition, is that after the first round, the pivot found the right place and will not move anymore. The second round will be applied to the subarrays `4,8,9,5,2` and `20,15,17,25,30`